# How to programmatically trigger Mouse Click on Picker on MAUI ( .Focus() is not the answer )

Tags: c#, maui, picker

If we click on the Picker on MAUI it will show the Selection Drop Down & we can use the Keyboard Arrow up and down to highlight the selection, and press enter / spacebar to confirm the selection ( which will change the SelectedIndex / SelectedItem and also fired the OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged ) --> This is what I am trying to do, I was working on POS System, where use can type in something on the Entry and press enter, which will do the Database Search and populate the result into Picker, i wish that user can simply use arrow up and down and press enter to confirm their selection.

.Focus() on the picker will not achieve what I want, consider the following Simple code snippet

**VIEW XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PickerTest.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Picker Title="Choose Item" x:Name="itemPicker"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding name}"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding selected_index}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding selected_item}"
                    SelectedIndexChanged="OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged"/>
            <Button
                x:Name="SearchButton"
                Text="Populate and Focus"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**VIEW C#**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using PropertyChanged;

namespace PickerTest;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public ItemViewModel vm { get; set; } 

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ItemViewModel();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemPicker.Focus();
        Debug.WriteLine(vm.items.Count + " : " + itemPicker.Items.Count);
    }

    private void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"[PICKER] select item {vm.selected_item.name} @ {vm.selected_index}");
        
        //cashierViewModel.OnAddToCart();
    }
}
```

**ITEM MODEL**

```
using System;
namespace PickerTest
{

    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public ItemModel( int _id, string _name)
        {
            id = _id;
            name = _name;
        }
    }
}
```

**ITEM VIEWMODEL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using PropertyChanged;

namespace PickerTest
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        public int selected_index { get; set; } = -1;
        public ItemModel selected_item { get; set; }
        public ItemViewModel()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
            {
                items.Add(new ItemModel(i, $"Item {i}"));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the short MP4 Video ( 84KB ) , to showcase what I mean
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AsZ0xAXsR01iinkC_6yaqu4UQUvC?e=0dqXHx
We can see that I can click the Picker, and press arrow up or down to highlight the selection and press enter to confirm the selection, but at the end, clicking the button to Focus will not show the Selection ( itemPicker.Focus(); )

**My Version**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (ARM 64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.6.0 Preview 4.0, Dot Net 7

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.5.0, Dot Net 7

Comment: Do you mean type something in the entry of the picker?

Comment: Yes, if you click the picker, you can use arrow key up and down to highlight the selection, and press enter / spacebar to confirm the selection ( which will change the SelectedIndex / SelectedItem and Fire OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged )

I wish to do so programmatically, because I perform the search typing on Entry Control, when the user press enter I will then do the server search, the items returned will be used to populate the Picker , AND I want the user to ( without using mouse ) to be able to just press up and down to do the selection

Comment: In the video, you click the button and call ```itemPicker.Focus()```. After that I could select item by pressing up and down.

Comment: I tried this on both Visual Studio 2022 Arm Preview Version 17.6.0 Preview 4.0 and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bit ) , Version 17.5.0. In both machine, clicking the button show nothing, and pressing arrow up or down also do nothing. But clicking the picker directly , works perfectly

Comment: That's weird. When I use the ```picker.Foucs()``` method, the picker show nothing. But then I press up and down, the item in picker will show and change.

Comment: In my case, executing picker.Focus(), and then pressing up or down will change the selected item in the picker, to show the picker we have to instead do the picker.Focus() and then press spacebar ( this will show the picker and arrow up or down will do HIGHLIGHT of the selection, when press enter / spacebar will do finalize the selection on the highlighted selection )... I wonder if it is possible to just do or simulate the "spacebar pressing after we have called the picker.Focus() ? because this show the picker as if we clicked the on the Picker itself using mouse

Comment: You could raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have added the Feature request , citing that ComboBox.DroppedDown was available for UWP C#. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15001